# Cordova SQLite Update Row

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

I need help to pass variable for SQLite update in Cordova Android after image upload. Here is my code.

```
function win(r) {
    console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode); 
    console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
    var kodes = r.response;
    upSuccess(kodes); // variable to be sent
}

        function upSuccess() {
            var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
            db.transaction(populateDBFUS, errorCBFUS, successCBFUS);
        }   
        function populateDBFUS(tx4UF) {
            tx4UF.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foto (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, kode, urut, file_name, status)');
        }
        function successCBFUS(tx4UF) {
            var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
            db.transaction(queryDBFUS, errorCBFUS);
        }       
        function queryDBFUS(tx4UF) {
            tx4UF.executeSql('UPDATE foto SET status = "1" ', [], querySuccessFUS, errorCBFUS); // need to add where statement with variable from upSuccess(kodes)
        }
        function querySuccessFUS(tx4UF, results) {
            myApp.alert("Upload OK");            
        }       
        function errorCBFUS(tx4UF, results) {
            myApp.alert("Fail Update");
        }
```

Thank you for your help in correcting my code.

Comment: Inside querySuccessFUS can you check value of results.rowsAffected if it's <1 implies you might have to insert the record first.

Comment: I already inserted data on table `foto`, just need to update the row on each image uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Variable to the query can be passed as follows :

```
tx4UF.executeSql("UPDATE foto SET status = "1" WHERE file_name = '"+filename+"' ;", [], querySuccessFUS, errorCBFUS);
```

pls try, hope this helps.

Comment: I tried your code but failed to update. This function didnt received the variable.

Comment: can you provide details on the variable name tried or update your post accordingly pls

Comment: Already updated code. On upSuccess(kodes) I received filename from uploaded image.

Comment: tx4UF.executeSql("UPDATE foto SET status = "1" WHERE file_name = ?", [filename], querySuccessFUS, errorCBFUS);